# How to make a greeting message with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot in the discord using discord.js and I want that when a person joins the server and open a chat with the bot, the bot is going to send the first message in the chat, something like "my name is charlie, how can I help you", how can I do that? All the examples I see are similar to the code below, but it is not working.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

EDIT 1:
I tried member.guild.channels.cache.find as said below and the error has disappeared, but the bot is not saying anything when I go to the chat, I think that channel is null so it returned without saying anything, how can I fix this?

EDIT 2:
Below you can see how my code is right now, I am trying to get my bot channel so that when a person gets in my server, the bot sends him a welcome message, but the channel was not found, I do not understand the problem.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.id === myBotId);
  if (!channel) {
    console.log("no channel");
    return;
  }
  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to use the `cache` property:

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.find();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
> if (!channel) return;
> channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
> ```

The code you posted sends a *Welcome to the server, ${member}!* message to the ***member-log*** channel in your guild. Since the code you are using looks fine, it is most likely that you don't have a channel with the name ***member-log***.

Create a ***member-log*** channel to fix the issue or find the channel in which you want to send the greeting like so `const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'your-channel-name');`